# Reversing a simple list in prolog

Tags: prolog

The following code will perform reverse on a list in prolog:

```
rev([], []).
rev([X|Xs], Ys) :- rev(Xs, Zs), append(Zs, [X], Ys).
```

I have no idea why it works, although the following is what I understand but I would appreciate further clarification.

The base case states that an empty list would result in a empty list.

I have no idea what is going on after this. Why is it calling the append function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to understand when the `append(Zs, [X], Ys)` is true. It says: it is true when you add item `[X]` to the end of list `Zs` and the result is equal to `Ys`.

Then `rev(Xs, Zs)` is true when `Zs` is reversed list of `Xs`.

So the whole algoritm says `Ys` is reversed list of `[X|Xs]` when you reverse the list `Xs` and then append `[X]` to the end of the reversed list.

In some procedural language you can write same algorithm with following code:

```
function List<T> Reverse(List<T> items)
{
    if (items.Count == 0)
         return items;

    var reversedList = Reverse(items.Skip(1));
    reversedList.Add(items.First());
    return reversedList;
}
```

Comment: why did someone down-vote your answer? i kind of get what you are saying so is this the only way to reverse a list in prolog?. upvoted and accepted answer.

Comment: I also don't know... No, there are another ways how to reverse a list. And there are more efficient algorithms, the one you posted is probably the most naive, but easy to understand especially when you are new to Prolog.